# Strange echo string from MySql

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database I have someting like `"Hello <<smt>>"` and I use PHP to echo this out `nl2br($msg['CONTENT']);` The output in `index.php` is:

```
"Hello <>"
```

Why's that?

And if I have in database something like `"Hello <smt>"` in `index.php` show me only `"Hello"`. What to do?

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools and format your question in a nicer way. E.g. mark code as code and similar. Also your question is not clear. For example, what did you expect instead?

Comment: Do you literally have the string `<smt>`? Or, is this some kind of example token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) only turns `\n` into `<br/>`.

> string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )
>
> Returns string with `<br />` or `<br>` inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

---

It has nothing to do with your problem. Your problem has to do with trying to display HTML tags. The browser recognize those tags and tries to parse them (like if it were a `<span>`).

To use those tags as display characters, just use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

**Example**

```
htmlentities(nl2br($msg['CONTENT']));
```

Answer (score 0):

by using htmlentities() u can get your values

[look demo here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/M4V8rf)